# Finding Fourier of $x^3$ by Fourier of $x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I found the cosine series of $x^2/2$ to be (by first finding Fourier sine series for $x$ on $(0,l)$ and then integrating that term by term)
$${x^2 \over 2}={l^2 \over 6}+{2 l^2 \over \pi^2}[\sum{(-1)^n \over n^2}\cos({n\pi x \over l})]$$

But my question is I have to find the sine series of $x^3$
 using the above.  I integrated $x^2/2$ to get
$${x^3 \over 6}={l^2 \over 6}x+{2 l^3 \over \pi^3}[-\sin({\pi x \over l})+{1 \over 2^3}\sin({2\pi x \over l})-{1 \over 3^3}\sin({3\pi x \over l})+\cdots+C]$$ where $C$ is the constant of integration.

**What happens to the constant  of integration**. What's the value of it? And how to find it. (In cosine, the constant could be found by finding the coefficient for the $n=0$ situation) Should $C=-{l^2 \over 6}x$? But I think $C=0$ but then how can I put the series in the  Fourier Sine series to be of the form $\sum A_n \sin({n\pi x\over l})$.

Comment: You have $x$ in the series too!

Answer (score 1):

$C$ is a constant and cannot **ever** be equal to $-\frac{\ell^2}{6}x$ if $x$ is the variable being integrated by. The point of the constant of integration is that when you differentiate it, it is equal to 0 (this is why it must be introduced).  Additionally, you should have the $C$ value on both sides, so that you can cancel them, and in effect $C=0$.

To see this last point, if it were not the case that we should have the same $C$ value on both sides, consider the following: $1=1$, so that by indefinitely integrating both sides we get $$x+C_1=x+C_2$$
Now, we can cancel $x$ on both sides to get $C_1=C_2$.

(Note, we had to already pick a distinguished antiderivative to do the above, but the idea is that if we choose the same distinguished antiderivative for both sides, then $C_1$ better equal $C_2$.)

As far as dealing with the $\frac{-\ell^2}{6}x$ term, you can write its Fourier cosine series, and add them component-wise.

Comment: "you should have the C value on both sides" means as $x^3/6+C=...+C$ But those constant necessary not equal right?

Comment: No, they must be the same.  Let me know if you'd like me to show this rigorously.

Comment: I tried to do this but I don't understand how they become equal.If you can show me how to do this it would be really helpful